# PHP for IIS Windows which version to install and source link

Tags: php, windows, iis

I´m trying to install PHP for IIS 7.5 running on Windows 7.

I came up with two different links:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53: The 5.3 version that requires Web PI to install.

http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.6-ts-VC11-x64: The ZEND site version of PHP for Windows, version 5.6.13 - 64bits.

Except for the versions, are those different PHP implementations ? Wich one should I choose as the correct one ?

Also, why does the ZEND site has a ZIP and a DEBUG version ?

This installation will be my application production site (I´m testing in a W7 machine and later will be moved to a WS2012).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: DEBUG has additional elements to allow for tracing and debugging during normal operation. If you don't need to debug, you don't want it as it reduces performance.

Comment: Check this Guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799141/instaling-php-on-windows-with-iis/34799142#34799142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Platform Installer one comes from the gallery where literally anyone can submit. You will have to trust the submitter and download. The version is quite old, and not sure who submitted it and when.

The ZEND is up to date, but so strictly follow the open approach, that it provides too many options for advanced users and pains to beginners.

Generally speaking you should now download from ZEND and choose a stable and recent release that your app can run on. That requires thorough testing on your side. For development you might download the debug build while for production you might switch to the release build.

It comes as a zip but there is nothing preventing you from extracting the files, configuring IIS to use them to host PHP.

You should be careful about the 64 bit version, as compared to the 32 bit version it is new and might not always work as you wished.