# Instaling PHP on Windows with IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis, installation

How can I install PHP on a Windows machine using Internet Information Services (IIS)?

Comment: Something like this might make for a good blog post.  But Stack Overflow is not your blog.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a guide than a question in the hope it helps many users who are looking for an easy beginner's proof installation guide:

First of all you need to have installed and running IIS on your machine, IIS doesn't comes by default, you have to add the characteristic from control panel -> Programs -> Windows Characteristics.

I had successfully installed PHP under IIS 5.1 (WinXP), IIS 7.5.7x (Win7) and IIS 10.0.10x (Windows 10) both x32 and x64 platforms and works great.

I resumed this guide in 10 easy steps:

1. Download the PHP version you like from http://windows.php.net/download/ make sure you download the Non-Thread Safe (NTS) versions of PHP.
2. Extract the files into 'C:\PHP\'.
3. Open then 'Internet Information Services Administrator IIS'.
4. Select the root item in the left panel.
5. Double click on 'Handler Mappings' (Asignaciones de Controlador).
6. On the right side panel click on 'Add Module Mapping' (Agregar asignacion de modulo..).
7. Setup the values like this:

   `Request Path: *.php
   Module: FastCgiModule
   Executable: C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe
   Name: PHP_FastCGI
   Request Restrictions: Folder or File, All Verbs, Access: Script`
8. Install 'vcredist_x64.exe' o 'vcredist_x86.exe' (Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable) https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30679
9. Setup your 'C:\PHP\php.ini', especially set the 'extension_dir ="C:\PHP\ext"'.
10. Reset Internet Information Services: In a command console type IISRESET.

Congratulations you have now PHP working on Windows!

Optionally you can install the 'PHP Manager for IIS' https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/ which is of great help to setup the ini file and track the log of errors (sadly It doesn't works on Win10 as far i know).

Remember to set 'index.php' as one of the default documents for IIS.

Glad to help.

Comment: You should ask it as a question, and then answer with the guide.

Comment: This worked for me in Win10 with the following changes: (7) FastCGI module didn't appear; I had to enable it in Windows Programs as described [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi) - the Win 8 section worked for Win 10.   And I didn't have to do (8) or (10).